# Trying to overlay an image onto a CALayer and retain the position from the subview (UITextView)

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, calayer

First time poster, looooooong time peruser. I'm using SwiftUI for the layout and UIRepresentables for the camera work. (Xcode 11.7), and trying to overlay an image onto a CALayer (for eventual export to video). The image was converted from a UITextView so the user is free to edit, pinch/zoom, and drag the text to their heart's content. After scouring SO for days, and reading Ray Wenderlich tutorials I've hit a wall. Screenshots below.

[Before: freeform text 'coffee' added to the view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YqVNm.jpg)

[After: exported movie still, 'coffee' text position is incorrect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T16Dp.jpg)

Below is the export function. I suspect I'm doing something wrong with `relativePosition`.

Thank you for **any suggestions**, this is my foray into writing an iOS app.

```
static func exportLayersToVideo(_ fileUrl:String, _ textView:UITextView){
    let fileURL = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: fileUrl)
    let composition = AVMutableComposition()
    let vidAsset = AVURLAsset(url: fileURL as URL, options: nil)
    
    // get video track
    let vtrack =  vidAsset.tracks(withMediaType: AVMediaType.video)
    let videoTrack: AVAssetTrack = vtrack[0]
    let vid_timerange = CMTimeRangeMake(start: CMTime.zero, duration: vidAsset.duration)
    
    let tr: CMTimeRange = CMTimeRange(start: CMTime.zero, duration: CMTime(seconds: 10.0, preferredTimescale: 600))
    composition.insertEmptyTimeRange(tr)
    
    let trackID:CMPersistentTrackID = CMPersistentTrackID(kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid)
    
    if let compositionvideoTrack: AVMutableCompositionTrack = composition.addMutableTrack(withMediaType: AVMediaType.video, preferredTrackID: trackID) {
        
        do {
            try compositionvideoTrack.insertTimeRange(vid_timerange, of: videoTrack, at: CMTime.zero)
        } catch {
            print("error")
        }
        
        compositionvideoTrack.preferredTransform = videoTrack.preferredTransform
        
    } else {
        print("unable to add video track")
        return
    }
    
    let size = videoTrack.naturalSize
    
    let parentlayer = CALayer()
    parentlayer.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: size.width, height: size.height)
    
    let videolayer = CALayer()
    videolayer.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: size.width, height: size.height)
    
    // Convert UITextView to Image
    let renderer = UIGraphicsImageRenderer(size: textView.bounds.size)
    let image = renderer.image { ctx in
        textView.drawHierarchy(in: textView.bounds, afterScreenUpdates: true)
    }
    
    let imglayer = CALayer()
    let scaledAspect: CGFloat = image.size.width / image.size.height
    let scaledWidth = size.width
    let scaledHeight = scaledWidth / scaledAspect
    let relativePosition = parentlayer.convert(textView.frame.origin, from: textView.layer)
    imglayer.frame = CGRect(x: relativePosition.x, y: relativePosition.y, width: scaledWidth,height: scaledHeight)
    imglayer.contents = image.cgImage

    // Adding videolayer and imglayer
    parentlayer.addSublayer(videolayer)
    parentlayer.addSublayer(imglayer)

    let layercomposition = AVMutableVideoComposition()
    layercomposition.frameDuration = CMTimeMake(value: 1, timescale: 30)
    layercomposition.renderSize = size
    layercomposition.animationTool = AVVideoCompositionCoreAnimationTool(postProcessingAsVideoLayer: videolayer, in: parentlayer)
    
    // instruction for overlay
    let instruction = AVMutableVideoCompositionInstruction()
    instruction.timeRange = CMTimeRangeMake(start: CMTime.zero, duration: composition.duration)
    let videotrack = composition.tracks(withMediaType: AVMediaType.video)[0] as AVAssetTrack
    let layerinstruction = AVMutableVideoCompositionLayerInstruction(assetTrack: videotrack)
    instruction.layerInstructions = NSArray(object: layerinstruction) as [AnyObject] as! [AVVideoCompositionLayerInstruction]
    layercomposition.instructions = NSArray(object: instruction) as [AnyObject] as! [AVVideoCompositionInstructionProtocol]
    
    //  create new file to receive data
    let dirPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true)
    let docsDir = dirPaths[0] as NSString
    let movieFilePath = docsDir.appendingPathComponent("result.mov")
    let movieDestinationUrl = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: movieFilePath)
    
    // use AVAssetExportSession to export video
    let assetExport = AVAssetExportSession(asset: composition, presetName:AVAssetExportPresetHighestQuality)
    assetExport?.outputFileType = AVFileType.mov
    assetExport?.videoComposition = layercomposition
    
    // Check exist and remove old files
    do { // delete old video
        try FileManager.default.removeItem(at: movieDestinationUrl as URL)
    } catch { print("Error Removing Existing File: \(error.localizedDescription).") }
    
    do { // delete old video
        try FileManager.default.removeItem(at: fileURL as URL)
    } catch { print("Error Removing Existing File: \(error.localizedDescription).") }
    
    assetExport?.outputURL = movieDestinationUrl as URL
    assetExport?.exportAsynchronously(completionHandler: {
        switch assetExport!.status {
        case AVAssetExportSession.Status.failed:
            print("failed")
            print(assetExport?.error ?? "unknown error")
        case AVAssetExportSession.Status.cancelled:
            print("cancelled")
            print(assetExport?.error ?? "unknown error")
        default:
            print("Movie complete")
            
            PHPhotoLibrary.shared().performChanges({
                PHAssetChangeRequest.creationRequestForAssetFromVideo(atFileURL: movieDestinationUrl as URL)
            }) { saved, error in
                if saved {
                    print("Saved")
                }
            }
            
        }
    })
}
```

}

Comment: Wait, SwiftUI or UIKit?

Comment: SwiftUI just for the layout, everything else is UIKit (UIRepresentables) for all the camera stuff.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the `x` position is correct, but the `y` is off. I think this is because the origin is at the bottom-left instead of the top-left. Try this:

```
var relativePosition = parentlayer.convert(textView.frame.origin, from: textView.layer)
relativePosition.y = size.height - relativePosition.y
imglayer.frame = CGRect(x: relativePosition.x, y: relativePosition.y, width: scaledWidth,height: scaledHeight)
```

Comment: Thank you! I will try this.

Comment: relativePosition is a point and does not have a property origin, did you mean relativePosition.y?

Comment: Ah, yes, my bad